# Why subprocess ffmpeg corrupt the file?

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have the following code, that reads a video and saves it in another path, the problem is that when the file is saved this is not reproducible?

```
import subprocess
import shlex
from io import BytesIO

file = open("a.mkv", "rb")

with open('a.mkv', 'rb') as fh:
    buf = BytesIO(fh.read())


args = shlex.split('ffmpeg -i pipe: -codec copy -f rawvideo pipe:')
proc = subprocess.Popen(args, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate(input=buf.getbuffer())
proc.wait()

f = open("a.mp4", "wb")
f.write(out)
f.close()
```

I need keep the buffers so, the video has the correct size, how can I solve this?

Comment: did you try to `print( out )` to see what you get ? Maybe it can show some information.

Comment: A very long bytes string with exadecimal codes

Comment: are you sure it should be `rawvideo` ?  `open()` can't convert it to `mp4`

Comment: if I don't put -f rawformat the output is empty

Comment: but how do you know that output is in `mp4` ? maybe it sends only pixels without compression.

Comment: I am using the same command in the shell and I can convert the file, the problem is that I need work with BytesIO, because I want to download and upload files from S3

Comment: I don't have `.mkv` so I tested with different files. When I use `.avi` as input then it gives correct output, when I use `.mp4` as input then it creates empty file and `err.decode()` shows information about problem. Did you check `err`? Did you check if code works in console with this file - maybe input file is wrong. As I know `.mkv` can use different codecs.

Comment: Why exactly can't you download and upload files from S3 without using Python at all? Put `ffmpeg ... < <(curl https://...)` in your shell command and you have output from `curl` going to stdin of `ffmpeg`. Mind, you can certainly do everything from Python you can also do from shell, but the _specific_ way you're doing it here is pretty unfortunate.

Comment: in particular, your current code requires the _entire_ input file to be read into memory before ffmpeg can be started at all

Comment: whereas if you use shell pipes or process substitutions, the content will be streamed -- ffmpeg will be able to start its work while curl (or whatever else you use for the network transfer) is still running. Again, Python can do all those same things, but arguably with more of a learning curve to do them correctly.

Comment: ...in particular, if I were writing this code in Python, I _would not_ use `communicate()`; instead, I'd have a thread that downloads the content and, as it's downloaded, writes it into `proc.stdin` -- that way you don't need to store more than a tiny piece of the file in memory at a time.

Comment: I run code with `.mkv` and later test with `ffprobe` and it shows problem with `moov atom not found`. I don't know how you run it in shell but if I run the same in shell `.... < a.mkv > a.mp4` then I also get the same error. So I always have problem with `.mkv` but it works with other formats like `.avi`

Comment: @furas thanks the problem is that the clients upload the content in mkv, I' will research more alot that, thanks for that point of view.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thanks I am not sure about if this consume a lot of memory in ram, i gues that but, this will be implemented in a flask endpoint and I don't know another options if you know, or if I can chat with you in someplace pleas tell me.

Comment: In general, if you're handling a large upload the common practice is to write it directly to a file to avoid consuming memory in your web service (disk, especially transient/temporary disk, is much cheaper!). If you're okay with longer latency (only starting the transcoding after the upload completely finishes), that can get you out of the business of needing to run ffmpeg with stdin from a pipe at all.

Comment: and isn't there any way of making a pipe of stream data like a node.js, for example, start a pipe that download bytes from s3, process with ffmpeg and upload to s3, that in node.js I guess can do byte by byte instead of fill the ram, so then in python the idea is create a temp file in the backend server and write then the files?

Comment: Yes, there's _absolutely_ a way, but that's not a question about `subprocess`, it's a question about the tools you're using to receive and send data, and I'm not prepared to do the work to figure out how it works in whatever specific web framework you happen to be using right now. I came in here to answer a subprocess question, not a flask question; it's been a decade since I last used flask for anything at all, and I've forgotten pretty much everything I used to know about it.

Comment: From a `subprocess` perspective, when you receive some data you write it to `proc.stdin`, and you should have `proc.stdout` directly attached to wherever you want it stored (or, if it's going to the web, maybe have a thread that's responsible for reading `proc.stdout` and uploading content as it comes in). Don't go byte-by-byte, go block-by-block; something like 4kb is basically the smallest chunk size you ever want to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ffmpeg-python](https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python)

```sh
pip install ffmpeg-python
```

And then:

```py
import subprocess
import shlex
import ffmpeg
from io import BytesIO

file = open("a.mkv", "rb")

with open('a.mkv', 'rb') as fh:
    buf = BytesIO(fh.read())

process = (
    ffmpeg
    .input('pipe:') \
    .output('a.mp4') \
    .overwrite_output() \
    .run_async(pipe_stdin=True) \
)

process.communicate(input=buf.getbuffer())
```

Comment: Is this meaningfully different from the behavior of the OP's current code in a way that can be reasonably expected to fix their bug? If so, how? (Read this as a request to [edit] more details on the specific mistake the OP made that this library avoids into the question text)

Comment: Thanks but the idea is get another buffer with the output, the answer is only a poc but the idea is get data from s3 in a buffer and upload into s3 from a buffer, I tried with that library, but I coulden't get the ourput buffer, do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

> and isn't there any way of making a pipe of stream data like a node.js, for example, start a pipe that download bytes from s3, process with ffmpeg and upload to s3, that in node.js I guess can do byte by byte instead of fill the ram, so then in python the idea is create a temp file in the backend server and write then the files

Yes, there is, but there is no prescribed mechanism in Python like in Node.js. You need to run your own threads (or `asyncio` coroutines), one to send data to and other to receive data from FFmpeg process. Here is a sketch of what I would do

```py
from threading import Thread
import subprocess as sp

# let's say getting mp4 and output mkv, copying all the streams
# NOTE: you cannot pipe out mp4
args = ['-f','mp4','-','-c','copy','-f','matroska','-']

proc = sp.Popen(args,stdin=sp.PIPE,stdout=sp.PIPE)

def writer():

   # get downloaded bytes data 
   data = ...

    while True:
        # get next data block
        data = self._queue.get()
        self._queue.task_done()
        if data is None:
            break
        
        try:
            nbytes = proc.stdin.write(data)
        except:
            # stdout stream closed/FFmpeg terminated, end the thread as well
            break
        if not nbytes and proc.stdin.closed:  # just in case
            break
   
def reader():

    # output block size
    blocksize = ... # set to something reasonable
                    # I use the frame byte size for rawdata in but would be 
                    # different for receiving encoded data

    while True:
        try:
            data = proc.stdout.read(blocksize)
        except:
            # stdout stream closed/FFmpeg terminated, end the thread as well
            break
        if not data: # done no more data
            break

        # upload the data
        ...

writer = Thread(target=writer)
reader = Thread(target=reader)

writer.start()
reader.start()

writer.join() # first wait until all the data are written
proc.stdin.close() # triggers ffmpeg to stop waiting for input and wrap up its encoding
proc.wait() # waits for ffmpeg
reader.join() # wait till all the ffmpeg outputs are processed
```

I tried out multiple different attempts using different approaches for my [`ffmpegio.streams.SimpleFilterBase` class](https://github.com/python-ffmpegio/python-ffmpegio/blob/054f2c69383da93347bab283cdb98af5a81662c7/src/ffmpegio/streams/SimpleStreams.py#L556) and settled on this approach.

Comment: Thanks, I will try, anyway if you know how to do this with your library for me is valid option, only I didn't find how to do it.

Comment: My library is geared towards read/write raw data not compressed data. So, its not quite applicable to your case without heavy modding (actually a simplification)